# C# MsiExec installs program to a wrong location

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I am using a C# code to install a program using a process which runs the msiexec, giving it the path to the MSI file.
This is the code I use:

```
string pathtoMsiFile = "\"" + msiPath + msiName + "\"";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i " + pathtoMsiFile + " /quiet";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

The strange thing is that when I try to install the program, for a certain version it installs it to the correct location I would expect to on `C:\path` but a different version it installs to `D:\path` for some reason. If I open the MSI itself manually, the default location there is `C:\path`. Any idea why?

Comment: You could add a /l*v /[path][logfile], in your startInfo arguments to produce a log of the install service, it will help you find out in which cases the path is no set properly

Comment: The most likely problem is that your MSI does not have a proper default install location, so when you run it with no UI it goes to the Windows default (probably the drive with most space). The stuff that sets the proper location is in your UI sequence, which is suppressed when you do /quiet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually it appears the problem is with the program the msiexec tried to install.
I am not that program's developer so I couldn't know the problem in advanced on my own.
The program had a custom action in its installation that set a variable representing the drive to install on as the one where the OS is installed. The problem is, that this action was invoked only through the installation's UI (when double clicking the MSI), but not when using a quiet CLI command to install it.